# Memory leak while parsing XML using TouchXML

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am using TouchXML to parse XML. While i am running the same in "Profile" Mode. I can able to see the memory leak. How can I fix this issue?

```
-(NSMutableArray *) grabXML:(NSData *)xmlData andQuery:(NSString *)query {  
    NSMutableArray *blogEntries = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];  
    CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil] autorelease];
    NSArray *resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:query error:nil];
    for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {
        NSMutableDictionary *blogItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        int counter;
        for(counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) {
            [blogItem setObject:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name]];
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < [[resultElement attributes] count]; i++) {
            CXMLNode *node = [[resultElement attributes] objectAtIndex:i];
            [blogItem setObject:[[resultElement attributeForName:[node name]] stringValue] forKey:[node name]];
        }
        [blogEntries addObject:[blogItem copy]];
        [blogItem release];
    }
    return [blogEntries copy];
}
```

I am calling the above method in the below mentioned format.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[self grabXML:responseData andQuery:@"//wsCheneliereResult"] autorelease];
```

Comment: You forgot the [rssParser release] call, didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[blogEntries addObject:[blogItem copy]];
```

Here is your mistake : you do not need to copy the `blogItem`, `addObject:` will actually `retain` its argument so that you can safely call `[blogItem release];` afterward.

And you most probably should not do `return [blogEntries copy]` either, and return just `blogEntries` : this is common programming habit that methods whose name does not contain 'copy' or 'create' return autoreleased values, such as you do not need to release them when you are done with them.

To sum up, I would go with :

```
-(NSMutableArray *) grabXML:(NSData *)xmlData andQuery:(NSString *)query {  
    NSMutableArray *blogEntries = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];  
    CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil] autorelease];
    NSArray *resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:query error:nil];
    for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {
        NSMutableDictionary *blogItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        int counter;
        for(counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) {
            [blogItem setObject:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name]];
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < [[resultElement attributes] count]; i++) {
            CXMLNode *node = [[resultElement attributes] objectAtIndex:i];
            [blogItem setObject:[[resultElement attributeForName:[node name]] stringValue] forKey:[node name]];
        }
        [blogEntries addObject:blogItem];
        [blogItem release];
    }
    return blogEntries;
}
```

and

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [self grabXML:responseData andQuery:@"//wsCheneliereResult"];
```

Comment: While it's true what you told about the copies, I don't think the changes will fix the memory leak. As I said in the comment above, the rssParser instance is never released.

Comment: You actually did not specify that `rssParser` was at fault. Plus, those are actual memory leaks you ought to take care of. There is no memory management mistake of `rssParser`, check the source code of `CXMLDocument` if possible, can't tell you more

Comment: Oops... didn't scroll to full right in source frame and missed the autorelease call at the end of the rssParser allocation line. Sorry.